# Lock alternative for TPL

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I use Task Parallel Library and I need to synchronize access to a method but since Tasks don't necessarily create threads for asynchronous operations, I can't rely on using locks.

```
void Foo()
{
    lock(SyncRoot)
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

What can I use instead of lock if I want to prevent simultaneous calls from multiple tasks to Foo? I need my tasks to call Foo, one by one.

---

- ContinueWith is not an option.
- I use .NET 4.

Comment: If you need serial calls why are you using TPL?

Comment: Can you show in what situation you think there will be a problem when using locks?

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you rely on locks? And `Task` that have code do use threads, they just take them from the `ThreadPool`, for better efficiency.

Comment: @Mark you were right, I was confused about the whole concept of locks, I guess. In the end, I couldn't find your answer to accept, though.

Comment: I deleted it because other answers were more popular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx):

> Behind the scenes, tasks are queued to the ThreadPool, which has been enhanced with algorithms (like hill-climbing) that determine and adjust to the number of threads that maximizes throughput.

So you can lock or any other threading synchronisation mechanism like ManualResetEvent or Memory barriers.

Answer (score 2):

As has been stated in other answers, you can do what you desire with the tools you have already, and this is handled for you by the thread pool. However, if you are set on a different method have you looked at a [`ConcurrentCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent) specifically a `BlockingCollection` this can be used to create producer/consumer queue that does what you want, something like the following might work for you

```
public class TaskQueue : IDisposable
{
    BlockingCollection<Action> taskX = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

    public TaskQueue(int taskCount)
    {
        // Create and start new Task for each consumer.
        for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Consumer);  
    }

    public void Dispose() { taskX.CompleteAdding(); }

    public void EnqueueTask (Action action) { taskX.Add(Action); }

    void Consumer()
    {
        // This seq. that we are enumerating will BLOCK when no elements
        // are avalible and will end when CompleteAdding is called.
        foreach (Action action in taskX.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            action(); // Perform your task.
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This actually helped. It's not the answer (at least the first right answer) to my question but thank you.